# VBA - Set Outlook 2010 Flag and then Forward Email

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm looking for some VBA that will set a flag on the selected email message and then forward it to a pre-defined email address. I've been able to set a flag for the message with the below VBA, but I'm not sure how to add the process of forwarding to a pre-defined email address.

```
Public Sub SetCustomFlag()

Dim objMsg As Object

With objMsg

.FlagRequest = "Assigned to JP " & objMsg.SenderName
.ReminderSet = True
.Save
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub SetCustomFlag()

Dim objMsg As Object
Dim newMsg As Object

With objMsg

.FlagRequest = "Assigned to JP " & objMsg.SenderName
.ReminderSet = True
.Save
End With

set newMsg = objMsg.Forward
newMsg.To = "theuser@domain.demo"
newMsg.Send

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting. I am getting an error at: Public Sub 

    newMsg.To = "theuser@domain.demo"

Comment: You never initialize objMsg. I simply copied your code and inserted the 3 extra lines. The assumption is your existing code works.

Comment: Dmitry, again thank you for your assistance. If you could please assist with complete the attached VBA it would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Public Sub SetCustomFlag()

Dim objMsg As Object
Dim newMsg As Object

With objMsg

.FlagRequest = "Assigned to JP " & objMsg.SenderName
.ReminderSet = True
.Save
End With

Set newMsg = objMsg.Forward
newMsg.To = "name@company.com"
newMsg.Send

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Again, you never initialize objMsg. Where does it come from? The first select message? The item opened in the active Inspector? Some other item retrieved by your other code?

Comment: You're correct, I do not think that it has been defined. To be honest, I don't know how to do that which is partially why I am here. The objective is to have a macro which will forward the currently selected message to a pre-defined, email address group, subject and flag status embedded within the macro. This will allow the receiving recipients a method to see who has begun addressing the original message.

Comment: Ok, initialize objMsg using the following "set objMsg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)"

Comment: I am very excited, we are 99% there! I see the flag on my side, but the recipient using Outlook does not see it on theirs. What needs to be done for the recipient to see the flag on their side?

Comment: Any flag and reminder properties are not transmitted to the message recipients. These properties can only be set locally.

Comment: Could it not be done with the "Track email messages that require follow up" function as shown by Microsoft? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-email-messages-that-require-follow-up-9d0f175f-f3e9-406d-bbf7-9c57e1f781cc

Comment: Yes, these are separate from the local reminder and flag - you will need to set http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8530001F etc. Take a look at the message with these properties set using OutlookSpy (clic kIMessage).